# Why is my printer only visible in system-config-printer?

Tags: arch-linux, cups

I've added a network printer using `sudo system-config-printer`, but it's not showing up in any print dialogues (only “Print to File” appears). How can this happen? The CUPS and Avahi daemons are running:

```
$ systemctl status | grep -E '[c]ups|[a]vahi'
             ├─org.cups.cupsd.service
             │ ├─5146 /usr/bin/cupsd -l
             │ └─5153 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
             ├─avahi-daemon.service
             │ ├─1361 avahi-daemon: running [l0b0k.local]
             │ └─1365 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
             └─cups-browsed.service
               └─1635 /usr/bin/cups-browsed
```

I tried [adding myself to the “lp” group](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#Connection_Interfaces), but that didn't help.

Comment: You didn't read pacman's message: you need to install `gtk3-print-backends`...

Comment: I never saw that message, because I install CUPS using Puppet. Thank you!